# Why is the BSON Null?

Tags: json, delphi, mongodb

Why is it that when I try and do something very similar to the TMongoWire demo program to load a document, I get a different result? On create of a page, I want to get all the company names and load them (eventually) into a combobox. This is the code I am playing with:

```
d:=BSON;
q:=TMongoWireQuery.Create(MongoWire);
try
  q.Query('mwx1.companies',nil);
  while q.Next(d) do
  begin
    s := BsonToJson(d);
    sl.add(d['CompanyName']);
    sl.Add(TBSONDocument(d).item['CompanyName'])
  end;
finally
  q.Free;
end;
```

At the point where I am assigning the JSON to S, the JSON is fully correct and the CompanyName has data in it. That line was there for testing only. But the next two lines both produce nothing (tried various ways to get the data) because it says that the value is null. If I inspect TBSONDocument(d) it shows all the correct information. So I am baffled as to why it isn't working. Any clues?

It starts out as an empty BSON, but when it's in the loop for the first iteration it contains the BSON of

> '{"_id":"ObjectID(\"524547512dcf91c1dc7476cb\")","Email":"2324","CompanyName":"T‌​est 1","Addr1":"fs","Addr2":"ertert","City":"iukuiuiku","State":"uikuiku","Zip":"dsf‌​","Country":"ff","Phone":"fdsd","SalesPerson":"sds","ContactPhone":"sdf","Contact‌​Email":"fsdf","ContactName":"f","DateCreated":"g2","website":"34","SMS":"23","Log‌​o":"23423","Status":"qwqw","Keywords":"3423","Shortcode":"qwqw","ParentID":"asda"‌​}'

Comment: At what point? It starts out as an empty BSON, but when it's in the loop for the first iteration it contains the BSON of '{"_id":"ObjectID(\"524547512dcf91c1dc7476cb\")","Email":"2324","CompanyName":"Test 1","Addr1":"fs","Addr2":"ertert","City":"iukuiuiku","State":"uikuiku","Zip":"dsf","Country":"ff","Phone":"fdsd","SalesPerson":"sds","ContactPhone":"sdf","ContactEmail":"fsdf","ContactName":"f","DateCreated":"g2","website":"34","SMS":"23","Logo":"23423","Status":"qwqw","Keywords":"3423","Shortcode":"qwqw","ParentID":"asda"}'

Comment: I'm wondering how we can diagnose the problem without having your data at hand. Can you present a code sample that we can run, or at least add enough information to the question for us to make progress. Please don't add detail in comments.

Comment: No offense David, but are you familiar with TMongoWire, have you used it before?

Comment: And no, I can not post a code example you can run. It hits my MongoDB server. This is a simple routine, it should be working. You are seeing the code minus the instantiation of the TStringList and the Var section defining stuff you should already know if you use TMongoWire. I was trying to just show the important stuff without the clutter.

Comment: I thought the issue was pure Delphi/JSON/BSON. If the issue is specific to your Mongo server then indeed I cannot help.

Comment: I opened an account with mongolab a while ago, I tried with above JSON and with me it works. Have you tried stepping into it with the debugger? If it is failing to get the correct key for some reason you should see why.

Comment: Stijn, which access method 'should' be the one that I use to get the CompanyName back out of the BSON? Does the code snipit look correct? Instead of using a serializer, I used your technique to manually build the JSON to save to the database, similar to my other post. When I use MongoVue to look at the data, it is in the same structure as the nwx1 database. The only difference that I see, is that you also create an id when you create the document, I have not tried that yet.